# SQL Developer 4.2.0 does not load

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Jeez, how hard is it to get SQL Developer to work.

Last month I downloaded the latest version and kept getting the cannot find ‘msvcr100.dll’ file error.

So I reverted back to an old version I had installed.

Now I have downloaded the latest version 4.2.0.

1 The first time I tried to launch it I was asked to set the JDK path.  So I set it to ‘C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121’.  Is this correct??

2 When I launch SQL Developer I get the initial splash screen, the progress bar does not get half way, and then it vanishes.

3 I went into the folder sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin and amended the file ‘sqldeveloper.conf’ i.e. SetJavaHome C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121

I still get the splash screen and then it vanishes.

Anyone with any ideas.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the same problem with the version with the built-in JDK and finally got it to work by:

1) Removing all other versions of Java from the system

2) Commenting the line under the #Set our usage tracking URI line in the sqldeveloper.conf file (sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin)

Not sure which one did the trick but hoping this helps someone else.

Comment: Got a pop up message saying new JAVA is available so I loaded it.  Once it loaded it stated "there are other versions of JAVA" do you want to remove them.  So, following your suggestion, I said YES.

Now SQL Developer loads....Cheers